# Using Custom ML Model with Service Now Predictive Intelligence

Tags: machine-learning, servicenow

I have a custom ML Model and would like to integrate it with ServiceNow's Predictive Intelligence.

I have been reading their documentation , but could only find usage of some ML API and classes, but no where I could see if there is a way to integrate it with custom ML model.
SNOW provides a class ClassificationSolution to use the in-built models, but I am not able to proceed on how to create our own custom model in Predictive Intelligence.

[Documentation](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-application-development/page/app-store/dev_portal/API_reference/ClassificationSolution/concept/ClassificationSolutionAPI.html)

ServiceNow Version - San Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer:

This can be achieved via [REST Action](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/learning-plans/rome/servicenow_application_developer/app_store_learnv2_rest_rome_exercise_create_a_rest_action)

Given external ML model which is hosted as Rest API, we can call ML Model via a Rest Action in Flow Designer.  We would then either take the output of your external ML model as input into a Predictive Intelligence model or vice versa via the Flow Designer Predictive Intelligence action.

For details:
[Service Now Community](https://www.servicenow.com/community/ai-intelligence-forum/using-custom-ml-model-with-service-now-predictive-intelligence/m-p/2502324/thread-id/239#M240)